# Enable TALK_DETECT for channel originated via ARI

Tags: php, asterisk, asterisk-ari

I'm trying to figure out a way to enable `TALK_DETECT` for an outgoing channel, but this does not seem possible for channel which his originated via `ARI`.

I thought about using a pre-dial handler for this, but it only seems possible when using the dialplan's `Dial()` function, not when originating with ARI endpoint.

I can't use a Local channel and direct the flow via a dialplan context, because due to asterisk's stupid architecture it causes all sorts of issues for me, so I'm pretty much locked out of using a dialplan.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to enable `TALK_DETECT` using the `/channels/{channelId}/variable` endpoint. It does not behave as expected though, which leads me to suspect it is listening on the transmitting side instead of the receiving one.

Comment: This is what I do for talk detection - how did you plan to use talk detection otherwise? As far as I understand the `TALK_DETECT` logic listens to both sides of the channel.

Comment: Correction: according to https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/773f424c7f7d54a8fa585deaa815cacdf1557e2b/funcs/func_talkdetect.c#L171 , `TALK_DETECT` only works on the remote side of the channel - i.e. an outgoing channel it would be the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten a chance to use ARI much, but have you tried the [record endpoint](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+17+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk17ChannelsRESTAPI-record)? You can tell it to record for a maxSilenceDuration and it will return the [talking_duration](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+17+REST+Data+Models#Asterisk17RESTDataModels-LiveRecording). You could use this to poll in a loop while you do something else.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't seem like a sane approach...

Comment: I did end up using recording in the end. This is the ONLY sane approach...

Answer (score 0):

Just add the TALK_DETECT variable when creating the channel by ARI. That should do it.